# jQuery animate each element but with a delay between each one

Tags: jquery

With the following I'm fading in and out a `div` on a loop that lasts forever.

```
function fadeOutFunc() {    
    $('.image-list .bottom').delay(5000).fadeOut(500).delay(5000).fadeIn(500,fadeOutFunc);
}
fadeOutFunc();
```

This is working fine but I need to change it a a bit. I have 4 `div`s that the selector targets. I want the first one to start animating after 5 seconds as it currently does. However I want the 2nd `div` to start animating after 6 seconds, the third `div` after 7 seconds, and the 4th `div` after 8 seconds.

The most scalable code would be one that would work even if there were more than 4 `div`s that matched the selector.

Comment: I've been stalking you :) **3rd** question today about this animate thing. You should really learn Javascript & jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through and increment the delay on each iteration. Try this:

```
$('.image-list .bottom').each(function(i) {
    var initialDelay = i * 1000 + 5000;
    $(this).delay(initialDelay).fadeOut(500).delay(5000).fadeIn(500,fadeOutFunc);
});
```

Comment: Ive tried to slightly modify your code to add a delay before the function is called again, but it doenst seem to work. Is this is syntax issue or am i going off in the wrong direction with this?:  $(this).delay(initialDelay).fadeOut(500).delay(8000).fadeIn(500).delay(800,fadeOutFunc);

Answer (score 0):

Use this to define the delay.

```
$('.image-list .bottom').each(function(index, item){ 
   var baseDelay = 5000;
   var delayDifference = 1000;
   delayForThisDiv = baseDelay + (index*delayDifference);
});
```

Comment: @Pinocchio, what's overly complicated about that?

Comment: 3 Variables for a delay number in this situation is unnecessary